# Understand JQuery Snippet code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me understand what this code snippet is doing? I'm maintaining a website and I think this is the source of a problem I am having.

```
function cust_addToCart(itemid, itemqty, options, viaajx, loadingf, callback) {
    var url = "/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?buyid=" + itemid + "&qty=" + itemqty;
    document.location.href = url;
}


$('#itemlist .addtocart-lnk').click(function() {
    $(this).next().find('.addtocart').click();
    return false; //Would this return a # for a link?
});
```

Comment: Is your question only about the last `return false`?

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes no sense. You don't state the problem you're having, but instead you're blaming some code that defines a function that's never called and embeds existential questions in its comments. Voting to close.

Comment: Like Hamidi mentioned, you really should state your problem.  On this site, people can give you paragraphs on each line.  Unless we know what the problem is, we're not sure which part you need more information on.

Answer (score 7):

This snippet:

```
$('#itemlist .addtocart-lnk').click(function() {
    $(this).next().find('.addtocart').click();
    return false; //Would this return a # for a link?
});
```

Is binding an event handler for the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event on elements with a class `addtocart-lnk` that are children of an element with id `itemlist`. Inside that event handler, the following:

```
$(this).next().find('.addtocart').click();
```

Is:

1. Finding the [next immediate sibling](http://api.jquery.com/next/) of the link that was clicked.
2. Then [finding](http://api.jquery.com/find/) every element with class `addtocart` that's a child of that sibling element,
3. Programmatically triggering the `click` event on those elements

This line:

```
return false;
```

Is preventing the default behavior of the link (which is hard to say without seeing your markup). Usually this prevents a link from being followed and the browser showing a new page.

---

This function:

```
function cust_addToCart(itemid, itemqty, options, viaajx, loadingf, callback) {
    var url = "/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?buyid=" + itemid + "&qty=" + itemqty;
    document.location.href = url;
}
```

Is building a url by concatenating the first string with the arguments `itemid` and `itemqty`, which are passed into the function. Setting `document.location.href` is directing the browser to that url.